# Write a program that determines whether two or more consecutive numbers are equal

Tags: c#

Write a program that determines whether, in a sequence of N numbers entered by the user, if two or more consecutive numbers are equal. Print out, if any, the position of the first elements of the sequence of equal numbers.

This is what i got so far but it isn't working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;

public class Exercises
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert the length of the sequence of numbers:");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int> seq = new List<int>();
        int equalSeqStart = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insert the number in position" + (i + 1) + ":");
            seq.Add(i);
            if ((seq[i] == seq[i - 1]) && (equalSeqStart == -1))
            {
                equalSeqStart = i - 1;
            }
        }

        if (equalSeqStart != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The sequence of equal numbers starts at" + (equalSeqStart));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no sequence of equal numbers");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger? That's the first step to determining the "some reason" why it's not working.

Comment: you never read any input from the user, instead you simply add the list indexes to the list

Comment: When `i == 0`, `seq[i - 1]` doesn't exist: you are going to have exception thrown

Comment: `seq[i - 1]` looks wrong (when i == 0 the list will be empty and there is nothing to access by index at all.)

Comment: Thank you so much. All the comments were super useful. Unfortunately i'm still a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to compare `prior` item with `current` one; you have no need in collections:

```
static void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine("Insert the length of the sequence of numbers:");

  //TODO: int.TryParse is a better choice
  int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  int equalSeqStart = -1;

  for (int i = 0, prior = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Insert the number in position {i + 1}:"); 

    //TODO: int.TryParse is a better choice
    int current = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (i > 0 && equalSeqStart < 0 && current == prior)
      equalSeqStart = i;

    prior = current;
  } 

  if (equalSeqStart != -1)
    Console.WriteLine($"The sequence of equal numbers starts at {equalSeqStart}");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("There is no sequence of equal numbers");
}
```

Comment: well the first step is actually inputting some data from the user